# onclick function apply to dynamic div in js

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I want to add on-click function to my dynamic div tag in JavaScript.

```
divElement = document.createElement('div');
divElement.onclick = moveImages(j, k);
```

I want to pass two parameter to the `moveImages()` function.

Answer (score 0):

In pure Javascript you need to define the **onclick** as a function, just like this:

```
divElement.onclick = function(e) {
    moveImages(j,k);
};
```

Without it, Javascript will simply call the function and assign the return value to the "property" **onclick**.

That (**e**) parameter is just in case you need to know where the click was and things like that.

Comment: You're welcome, please, vote in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by doing the following:

````
var divElement = document.createElement("div");

function moveImages(j, k){
 /* ... */
}

divElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    moveImages(j, k);
}, false);```
````

Comment: Thank you... lot